# Android searchview saves wrong state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-search

In my fragment I save two simple search view. If i will fill second search view , if I will leave activity ( marked to be killed from dev options) and come back again, android restores search view querys automatically, but they have wrong texts ( second query will be set for first one too) . How can I force android not to save state automatically for my searchviews ?

configureSearchViews is called from onViewCreated

```
   private fun configureSearchViews() {
    ibFirstView.show()
    svFirstField.queryHint = getString(R.string.enter_stop)
    svFirstField.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
    setFirstFieldQueryTextListener()
    svFirstField.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(this)

    svSecondField.queryHint = getString(R.string.enter_number)
    svSecondField.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
    setSecondFieldQueryTextListener()
    svSecondField.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(this)
}
```

and here is my xml file:

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llFirsField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/view_loc_selector_height"
            android:background="@drawable/view_rounded_white_bg"
            android:layoutAnimation="@null"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null">

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/svFirstField"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/view_loc_selector_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                android:queryHint="@string/enter_bus_stop"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextDarkGray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_search" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ibFirstView"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/view_loc_selector_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_pin" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:id="@+id/vDividerSelector"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/llFirsField" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSecondField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/view_loc_selector_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/vDividerSelector"
            android:background="@drawable/view_rounded_white_bg"
            android:layoutAnimation="@null"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null">

            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/svSecondField"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                android:queryHint="@string/enter_buss_number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextDarkGray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_search"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in the source code of `SearchView` that it is inflating an edit text inside. When you put two SearchView, you put basically two edit text with the same id to your screen.

As those edit texts have same ids, when android is restoring their state, it is using the second one's query(cause android is using id-value pairs to restore state using a SparseArray).

To fix this you can basically use `onSaveInstanceState` to save your queries and `onRestoreInstanceState` to restore from activity kill.